# How to bring my assets to US

Tags: taxes, india, foreign-income

I am a naturalized US citizen. I want to bring my assets from India to US. My assets are sold and in a bank account. What are the steps to bring the money to the US? It is worth 1.25 Crore and I have already paid the 20% tax in India.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the steps to bring the money to the US? It is worth 1.25 Crore and I have already paid the 20% tax in India.

Under the [Liberalized Remittance Scheme](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FAQView.aspx?Id=66) an Individual can repatriate funds upto USD 250,000 without any paperwork.

However most banks would be cautious and request for [Form 15CA and Form 15CB](https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFiling/Portal/StaticPDF/Form15CA_CB.pdf) if you are moving funds from NRO Account. Form 15 CA you would need to declare why you are moving the said funds. The Form 15 CB is to be filled by  Chartered Account certifying that relevant taxes have been already paid to Income Tax.

Most Banks would offer these services. Compare the Fx Rate and Fees before you make a decision as to which Bank to proceed with.