# Money from India to USA

Tags: united-states, india, international-transfer

I am a US citizen and own a house in India. I also have some business interests in India that I'm planning to wind up.

I would like to know how to bring my money to US? What sort of interest will I have to pay...and where? As a US  citizen do I pay tax in India?

Comment: Your nationality is probably irrelevant to whether or not you owe tax in the country in which you do business. You should check whether the USA and India have a tax reciprocity agreement. If not, you will have to pay tax in both countries.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how to bring my money to US?

By wire transfer. You will need a CA. Form 15CA and 15 CB need to be filled.

> What sort of interest will I have to pay...and where?

There is no interest to be paid. The sale of house / business will result in a capital gains event. Taxes need to be paid on capital gains in India.

> As a US citizen do I pay tax in India?

Yes. The scenerio you describe creates a tax event for you in India.

Related question: [Transferring Money from India](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87830/transferring-money-from-india)